# IOS app crashes after sending request (object releases)

Tags: dealloc, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am new Obj_c, cant understand the stack traces, which i found during the crash:

i simply send a request to server but before receiving the response app crashes.

Anybody can help me plz!!

[image]